# Increasing decimal in table chart Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, ndvi, table, time-series, chart

I have code that generates NDVI times series chart. The values are with 3 decimal places. I want to increase the decimal places to 4 or 5. Is there a way of doing that?

My code:

```
// Load raster data (COPERNICUS/S2_SR).
// Load vector data (shapefile).
var fc = ee.FeatureCollection(user_account+folder+shpfile_name).sort('Group');
var S2 = ee.ImageCollection(image_collection)
        .filterDate(first_date, last_date)
        .filterBounds(fc)
        .filterMetadata('CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE', 'less_than', 18);

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
print(S2)
print(fc)           // CRS must be WGS84 (for the shapefile)          

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//Image Expression for calculating NDVI----------------------------------------------
var band_1 = 'B4'
var band_2 = 'B8'

var addNDVI = function(image) {
  var NDVI = image.expression(
  '(B8-B4)/(B8+B4)',
  {
    'B4': image.select('B4'),
    'B8': image.select('B8'),

  }).rename('NDVI');
  //NDVI index
  return image.addBands(NDVI.add(ee.Image(0.0)));
  //Add 0.0 value to NDVI (currently not in use)
};

// Calculate NDVIfor images in the Image collection 
var S2_withNDVI = ee.ImageCollection(S2).map(addNDVI);          
print(S2_withNDVI)

//Export NDVI Time Series into a Scatter Chart and a CSV format              
TimeSeries = Chart.image.seriesByRegion(
S2_withNDVI, fc, ee.Reducer.mean(), 'NDVI', 3, 'system:time_start', fc_ID)
    .setChartType('ScatterChart')
    .setOptions({
      title: 'NDVI Time Series For '+ Name,
      vAxis: {title: 'NDVI', format: 'Decimal'},
      hAxis: {title: 'Date'},
      lineWidth: 1,
      pointSize: 4,
      series: {
}});
/ Display.
print(TimeSeries); 
// Compute 3X3 standard deviation kernel (SD) as texture of the NDVI.
var addTexture_3X3_stdDev = function(image) {
var texture = image.select('NDVI').reduceNeighborhood({
reducer: ee.Reducer.stdDev(),
kernel: ee.Kernel.square(1),
}).rename('NDVI_3X3_stdDev')
return image.addBands(texture.add(ee.Image(0.0)));
};
var S2_Analysis = ee.ImageCollection(S2_withNDVI).map(addTexture_3X3_stdDev);
print(S2_Analysis)

//Export 3X3 kernel NDVI stdDev Time Series into a Scatter Chart and a CSV format              
var TimeSeries = Chart.image.seriesByRegion(
S2_Analysis, fc, ee.Reducer.mean(), 'NDVI_3X3_stdDev', 3, 'system:time_start', fc_ID)
    .setChartType('Table')
    .setOptions({
      title: 'NDVI 3X3 stdDev kernel Time Series For Corn Field'+ Name,
      vAxis: {title: 'stdDev', format: 'Decimal'},
      hAxis: {title: 'Date'},
      lineWidth: 1,
      pointSize: 4,
      series: {
}});
// Display.
print(TimeSeries);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can specify with a format pattern.  ie: add `"format: '0.00000'"` to the axis block you want to use it in.

Comment: OK, that changes only the value of the chart axis. I want to change the values inside the chart. the values of the NDVI on every date.

Comment: You would probably have to build your own datatable (https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/customizing_tooltip_content#using-html-tooltips) and use a custom formatter (https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#formatters).  Easier, I expect, to just multiply by 1000 before making the chart.